# Функция all странный результат

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему результат функции `all` с аргументом пустой список `[]` — `True`?

```
print(all([]))
```

Хотя если `bool([])` или `if []` — `False` логично

Answer (score 2):

Это из-за алгебры. Понятно как определить `all` для непустых списков. Если в списке все элементы истинны, значение `all` - `True`. Обратите внимание что `all` обладает следующим свойством: `all(a + b) = all(a) and all(b)`, где `a` и `b` списки, а `+` это конкатенация. Но тогда верно что

> ```
> all(a) = all(a + []) = all(a) and all([])
> ```

Последнее равенство может быть верным только если `all([])` - истина. Поэтому естественно приписать пустому списку истину.

Что касается `bool([]) == False`, то это просто специальное правило языка. Будь моя воля, я бы вовсе не приводил списки к логическим значениям. Вместо `bool(a)` можно было бы проверять `len(a) == 0`. Но так решил автор языка.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что любая последовательность будет иметь случай []? —> a = [1, 2, 3] -all-> 1 and 2 and 3 and []

Comment: Не совсем точно выразились. `all` можно определить рекурсивно как `all([head, *tail]) -> bool(head) and all(tail)`. Тогда логично приписать пустому списку значение `True`. `all = lambda lst: True if not lst else bool(lst[0]) and all(lst[1:])`.

Answer (score 1):

`all` - эквивалент `False not in a`:

```py
def all(a: list[bool]) -> bool:
    return False not in a
```

Comment: Ваше объяснение не плохо, но и не точно. `all([[]])` -> `False`. `False not in [[]]` -> `True`. Лучше написать `False not in map(bool, a)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну тогда вот точный эквивалент (наверное): `return len([x for x in a if not x]) == 0`